# Regex select certain character

Tags: regex

What's the regex of highlighted area in below picture? It's a variables 
[enter image description here][1]

Comment: Need better explaination, and you to provide your code

Comment: I have reword my question please have a look @SubjectDelta

Comment: I still need more info for a better answer... Are you using Javascript/jQuery to find all the option with NZD 0.00? Or what?

Answer (score 0):

If you whant the NDZ of the "467883******0303" only

```
/Travel NZD NZP : 467883\*\*\*\*\*\*0303      \:      NZD (\d+.\d+)/
```

Otherwise...

```
/Travel\sNZD\sNZP\s\:\s\d{6}\*{6}\d{4}\s{6}\:\s{6}NZD\s(\d+.\d+)/
```

You'll find the example [here](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/lp3)